# Swift-UITableView Paging with textview inside

Tags: swift, uitableview, textview, scrollview, paging

I have a TableView with paging enabled and there are dynamic cells with first one is UITextView and second static, third UITextView, fourth static... goes like that. The thing i want is textview scrolls inside, when it reached bottom then tableview scrolls and goes next cell. How is that possible?